# list view not showing when last record deletes using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list view grid with delete say I have a pagination links on the page (previous 1 2 Next). when I am trying to delete last record in the second page the listview doesn't show up.I have done binding in the server side and calling when a record delete. If the second page is having more than two records then grid shows. Any one have idea why this issue coming ? But when I reload page the grid showing.

I have a listview grid  as

```
<asp:ListView   ID="lvSurvey" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder2"
ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder2"  OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChangingSurvey" OnItemCommand="lvSurvey_ItemCommand"  >

---
--
</asp:ListView>
```

I also have pagination as

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder2"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <tr>
            <td colspan = "3">
                <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager2" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvSurvey" PageSize="1">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                            ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton = "false" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I am able to display record from sql server and also pagination shows in the page. I have a delete button in grid as

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClientClick="return getConfirmation(this, 'Please confirm','Are you sure you want to delete?');"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Order_Survey_ID") +  "|" + Eval("Status") %>'
                            CommandName="DeleteSurveyObject"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>          <br />



             </td>
        </tr>


</ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

I am also able to delete and have done server coding for deletion.But when only one record in second link, not able to show listview at the time of deletion.

```
protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        (lvOrderInstall.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
        this.GetAllOrderInstall();
      TabName.Value = "installation";

    }

  protected void lvSurvey_ItemCommand(object source, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
if(e.CommandName == "DeleteObject")
            {
                string[] param = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|');
                hfInstallID.Value = param[0].ToString();

                DELETEINSTALL(int.Parse(hfInstallID.Value), clsCommon.gConstDTOMode_Delete, clsCommon.gConstActive_Status);
                GetAllOrderInstall();

                TabName.Value = "installation";
                litMsg.Text = "Record deleted successfully";
            }
       }
```

Comment: Bind your listview in code-behind in `if(!isPostBack)`

Comment: It doesn't work I have already given this in code

Comment: Can u refer https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Show-data-in-ListView-from-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `GetAllOrderInstall();` at the end of `lvSurvey_ItemCommand` function to rebind the list view after updation.

```
protected void lvSurvey_ItemCommand(object source, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                if(e.CommandName == "DeleteObject")
                {
                    string[] param = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|');
                    hfInstallID.Value = param[0].ToString();

                    DELETEINSTALL(int.Parse(hfInstallID.Value), clsCommon.gConstDTOMode_Delete, clsCommon.gConstActive_Status);
                    GetAllOrderInstall();

                    TabName.Value = "installation";
                    litMsg.Text = "Record deleted successfully";
                }

                GetAllOrderInstall();
           }
```

Comment: It was like early but when I was doing some how it went inside.Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome dude. I am sorry i didn't got what you were trying to say in comment :). The problem i think was that after deleting a record you were not updating the list-view.